# How to download protected web page using Java

Tags: java, security, download, automation, html

We have a task, to design a class which can download source of any web page.  But when I try to test my code and fetch page like `http://anidb.net/perl-bin/animedb.pl?show=main` – nothing is working.

A standard code like this fails:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL link = new URL("http://www.anidb.net/");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(link.openStream()));

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Here is the result I got:

```
&#352;wq>&#178;"¦§5&#180;_&#239;__&#199;U&#186;=&#244;&#217;&#246;?k&#352;}~“bd`?l“&#207;&#231;z&#162;&#199;&#234;&#245;>_"?j&#215;‰R“y}K&#184;\&#204;c_DL&#217;&#170;&#207;_
    –&#243;Mm_&#188;_0”•&#246;°&#203;C_a&#237;&#189;s&#238;¤&#236;&#193;S ‚>dC0&#236;s_–y&#185;&#241;±&#207;&#221;&#220;A&#248;%&#200;_&#228;&#214;&#225;__&#230;©A@,4x„&#352;¶_&#235;&#201;&#402;?
```

I have tried everything: cookies, header files but nothing seems to work. If you have some hint for me, I will appreciate it.

Comment: This doesn't take character encoding into account anyway. Use a library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Writing a http client, you have to take gzip encoding into account as well as chunked transfer. Its better to use a library to download a webpage.

Try something like this:
http://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/

Answer (score 2):

The site you referred to in your question doesn't seem to honor the 'Accept` request header nor they are setting the 'Content-Encoding' response header correctly, which I think is not correct.

Anyways, you can also use the `java.util.zip.GZipInputStream` to read the response in plain text format:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    URL link = new URL("http://www.anidb.net/");
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) link.openConnection();

    GZIPInputStream in = new GZIPInputStream(con.getInputStream());
    byte[] b = new byte[1024];
    StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
    while (in.read(b) > 0)
    {
        content.append(new String(b));
    }
    System.out.println(content);
}
```

Comment: It's all about gzip. I should use java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.
Thank you.